# How to intercept customer order in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer, plugin, extension-attributes

When an order is submitted, I need to write data to extension attributes. I need to either create an event observer or plugin. How do I do this the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 2 way to handle order place

**1. Event**

**Acme/StackExchange/etc/events.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="acme_stackexchange_observer_sales_order_place_after"
                  instance="Acme\StackExchange\Observer\Sales\OrderPlaceAfter"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**Acme/StackExchange/Observer/Sales/OrderPlaceAfter.php**

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Observer\Sales;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class OrderPlaceAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var Order $order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');
        // your logic here
    }
}
```

**2. Plugin**

**Acme/StackExchange/etc/di.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface">
        <plugin name="Acme_StackExchange_Plugin_Sales_Api_OrderManagementInterfacePlugin"
                type="Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterfacePlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Acme/StackExchange/Plugin/Sales/Api/OrderManagementInterfacePlugin.php**

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Sales\Api;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface;

class OrderManagementInterfacePlugin
{
    public function afterPlace(
        OrderManagementInterface $subject,
        OrderInterface $result,
        OrderInterface $order
    ): OrderInterface {
        // your logic here

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Victor!